# JavaScript escape stars on regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a serial number from a zigbee packet (i.e get from 702442500 *13*32*702442500#9).

So far, I've tried this:

```
test = "*#*0##*13*32*702442500#9##";
test.match("\*#\*0##\*13\*32\*(.*)#9##");
```

And this:
test.match("*#*0##*13*32*(.*)#9##");

With no luck. How do I get a valid regular expression that does what I want?

Comment: You are passing a string. A regular expression is delimited by `/.../`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `"*#*0##*13*32*702442500#9##".match(/\d/g).join("")`

Comment: What's allowed in that string? `[0-9#*]+` will match digits, hashes and stars. If that's what you want, `if (/^[0-9#*]+$/.test(string)) { happy }`

Comment: @FelixKling: The `.match()` method converts it to a regex. Multitut: You'll need to double escape the `*` since a `\ ` in a string literal also starts an escape sequence. Doing `\\*` will give you the literal `\*` sequence, which will be turned properly into the regex you want. `test.match("\\*#\\*0##\\*13\\*32\\*(.*)#9##");`

Comment: @cookiemonster: Sure, but that doesn't make the string a regular expression. If passed as a regular expression, `\*` would work as expected.

Comment: @cookiemonster, that's what I was asking. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex matches the number which has atleast three digits,

```
/([0-9][0-9][0-9]+)/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pC9eE1)

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Multitut You could also use `/(\d{3,})/`, if you're going for the shortest statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the big number, you can use:

```
/\*#\*0##\*13\*32\*([^#]+)#9##/
```

Note that I use delimiters  `/` that are needed to write a pattern in Javascript (without the regexp object syntax). When you use this syntax, (double)? quotes are not needed. I use `[^#]+` instead of `.*` because it is more clear and more efficent for the regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to grab that portion of the string would be to use

```
var regex = /(\*\d{3,}#)/g,
    test = "*13*32*702442500#9";

var match = test.match(regex).slice(1,-1);
```

This captures a `*` followed by 3 or more `\d` (numbers) until it reaches an octothorpe. Using the global (`/g`) modifier will cause it to return an array of matches.

For example, if

```
var test = "*13*32*702442500#9
            *#*0##*13*32*702442500#9##";
```

then, `test.match(regex)` will return `["*702442500#", "*702442500#"]`. You can then slice the elements of this array:

```
var results = [],
    test = "... above ... ",
    regex = /(\*\d{3,}#)/g,
    matches = test.match(regex);

matches.forEach(function (d) {
    results.push(d.slice(1,-1));
})
// results : `["702442500", "702442500"]`
```